# Excluded files take long to process when downloading using SCP protocol with WinSCP

Tags: download, scp, winscp

I am trying to download a folder with SCP protocol using WinSCP by excluding some common extensions like .class .gif
For some reason WinSCP is ignoring me. The files are either still downloaded (although discarded) or they are processed some other way, that takes time.

What am I doing wrong?

This is how I configured the download:

[image]

[image]

Small portion of the session log of WinSCP:

```
> 2021-02-05 16:03:24.991 scp: error
< 2021-02-05 16:03:25.307 E
. 2021-02-05 16:03:25.307 Sending NULL.
< 2021-02-05 16:03:25.460 T1479214906 0 1612380313 0
. 2021-02-05 16:03:25.460 Sending NULL.
< 2021-02-05 16:03:25.591 C0644 5878 PrinterDetails_jsp.class
. 2021-02-05 16:03:25.591 File "/var/tomcat/tomcat001_xeroxPrinterApp/work/Catalina/xerox/xeroxPrinterApp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/PrinterDetails_jsp.class" excluded from transfer
. 2021-02-05 16:03:25.591 Sending SCP error (1) to remote side:
> 2021-02-05 16:03:25.591 scp: error
< 2021-02-05 16:03:25.923 T1575667910 0 1612558660 0
. 2021-02-05 16:03:25.923 Sending NULL.
< 2021-02-05 16:03:26.060 D0755 0 plugin
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.060 File: '/var/tomcat/tomcat001_xeroxPrinterApp/work/Catalina/xerox/xeroxPrinterApp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views' [2019-12-06T21:31:50.000Z] [0]
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.060 Sending NULL.
< 2021-02-05 16:03:26.209 T1479214910 0 1575366742 0
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.209 Sending NULL.
< 2021-02-05 16:03:26.345 C0644 8443 HeaderlessPage_jsp.java
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.345 File: '/var/tomcat/tomcat001_xeroxPrinterApp/work/Catalina/xerox/xeroxPrinterApp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/plugin' [2016-11-15T13:01:50.000Z] [8443]
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.345 Sending NULL.
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.345 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.492 SCP remote side confirmation (0)
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.492 Sending NULL.
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.492 Preserving timestamp [2016-11-15T13:01:50.000Z]
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.492 Transfer done: '/var/tomcat/tomcat001_xeroxPrinterApp/work/Catalina/xerox/xeroxPrinterApp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/plugin/HeaderlessPage_jsp.java' => 'C:\temp\xeroxPrinterApp_UPGRADE\work\Catalina\xerox\xeroxPrinterApp\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\views\plugin\HeaderlessPage_jsp.java' [8443]
< 2021-02-05 16:03:26.645 T1479214910 0 1612380316 0
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.645 Sending NULL.
< 2021-02-05 16:03:26.777 C0644 6876 HeaderlessPage_jsp.class
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.777 File "/var/tomcat/tomcat001_xeroxPrinterApp/work/Catalina/xerox/xeroxPrinterApp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/views/plugin/HeaderlessPage_jsp.class" excluded from transfer
. 2021-02-05 16:03:26.777 Sending SCP error (1) to remote side:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you assume that WinSCP downloads all files, even excluded ones, and somehow discards them only afterwards. It does not.

It looks like you assumption is based on the fact, that processing of the excluded files take some time. It's indeed possible with the SCP protocol. The SCP protocol works quite differently to SFTP, FTP, WebDAV and the likes, when it comes to a folder download.

With the other protocols, the client (WinSCP) fetches a list of files in the folder (that being a batch operation, is quite effective, when there are lot of files in the folder). And it then picks the files it's interested in and asks the server for those files. The exclusion of the files is purely a local computation, so it's nearly instant.

But with the SCP protocol, the folder download is controlled by the server only. The server offers the files one by one, and the client have to interactively accept/reject the files. It's kind of a dialogue. Particularly if a latency to the server is big, the dialogue can be time consuming. Each file, even the excluded ones, will take some time to process, as there's a data exchange involved, when processing them.

---

Try switching to the SFTP protocol. Most servers that support SCP, support SFTP too. For your use case, the SFTP should be more efficient.